# How to get task_struct in user level code

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I want to read task_struct in my user level code, without making any of my own syscall to get into kernel. 
Is there any system call available for mapping task_struct into user level code?

Comment: Most probably not. Why do you want to access it?

Comment: you need to make first a kernel module to get the task_struct list .now after that make file operation on your module to send these task_struct information to your user-level application